# cant drag child out of parent after dragging in

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have twitter bootstrap rows and columns. If I drag row into column, I can't drag it back. Html:

```
<div class="demo .container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <span class="drag label label-default">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i>
            drag
        </span>

    <div class="col-md-12 column">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="drag label label-default">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i>
            drag
    </span>
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="drag label label-default">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i>
            drag
    </span>
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.demo, .demo .column').sortable({
    handle: '.drag',
    connectWith: ".column",
    placeholder: "ui-sortable-placeholder",
    start: function(e, ui ){
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
    },
});
})
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1obcs1vc/4/).
Does anyone has idea how can I make so that after dragging row into column I could drag it back and have three rows siblings ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Need just add `.demo` to `connectWith`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.demo, .demo .column').sortable({
    handle: '.drag',
    connectWith: ".column, .demo",
    placeholder: "ui-sortable-placeholder",
    start: function(e, ui ){
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
   },
});
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1obcs1vc/5/